# Marklogic 8 rest extension multpart/form-data with file upload issues

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I wrote a small rest extension in ML8 which basically stores the file uploaded into the ml content database.. when I do this I get the following exception

```
<error-response xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error">
<status-code>500</status-code>
<status>Internal Server Error</status>
<message-code>INTERNAL ERROR</message-code>
<message>XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")($context, $service-params, $input) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.</message>
</error-response>
```

But I did set the declare option xdmp:update "true"; Following is the code..

```
module namespace repoLoad = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad";

declare namespace rapi = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api";

declare default function namespace  "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
declare option xdmp:update "true";

(: Function responding to GET method - must use local name 'get':)
declare function repoLoad:get($context as map:map, $params  as map:map) as document-node()*
{
    repoLoad:notSuportedMsg($context)
};

(: Function responding to PUT method - must use local name 'put'. :)
declare function repoLoad:put($context as map:map, $params  as map:map, $input as document-node()*) as document-node()?
{
    repoLoad:notSuportedMsg($context)
};

(: Func responding to DELETE method - must use local name 'delete'. :)
declare function repoLoad:delete($context as map:map,$params  as map:map) as document-node()?
{
    repoLoad:notSuportedMsg($context)
};

(: Function responding to POST method - must use local name 'post'. :)
declare function repoLoad:post($context as map:map, $params  as map:map,$input as document-node()*) as document-node()*
{
    let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")
    let $contentType := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")
    let $log := xdmp:log("File Name : " || $filename)
    let $log := xdmp:log("Content Type : " || $contentType)


    let $uri := "/documents/"||$filename
    let $_ := xdmp:document-insert($uri, xdmp:get-request-field("upload"),(xdmp:default-permissions()), ("raw"))

    let $output := json:object()
    let $_ := (
        map:put($output, "Name", $filename),
        map:put($output, "Mime-Type", $contentType)
    )
    return document {xdmp:to-json($output)}

};



declare private function repoLoad:notSuportedMsg($context as map:map) as document-node()*
{
    let $_ := map:put($context, "output-status", (501, "Not Supported HTTP method"))
    let $output := json:object()
    let $errorResponse := json:object()
    let $_ := (
        map:put($errorResponse, "statusCode", 501),
        map:put($errorResponse, "message", "Not Supported HTTP method")
    )
    let $dummpy := map:put($output, "errorResponse", $errorResponse )
    return document {xdmp:to-json($output)}
};
```

And Following is error trace in log files

```
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")($context, $service-params, $input) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy, at 877:20,
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in extut:call-service("repoLoad", "POST", xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy"), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>), map:map(), document{binary{""}}) [1.0-ml]
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $extension-name = "repoLoad"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $method = "POST"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $service-params = map:map()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $input = document{binary{""}}
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy, at 792:14,
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in extut:invoke-service("repoLoad", "POST", "query", xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy"), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>), map:map(), document{binary{""}}, fn:false()) [1.0-ml]
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $extension-name = "repoLoad"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $method = "POST"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $default-txn-mode = "query"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $service-params = map:map()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $input = document{binary{""}}
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $in-txn = fn:false()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $txn-curr = "query"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $annotation = ()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $txn-mode = "query"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 254:8,
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in rsrcmodqry:resource-post("repoLoad", map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>), map:map(), document{binary{""}}, fn:false(), local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $resource-name = "repoLoad"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-types"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">te...</map:map>)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $resource-params = map:map()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $input = document{binary{""}}
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $in-txn = fn:false()
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 219:4,
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in rsrcmodqry:exec-post(map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="content-type"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">mu...</map:map>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="upload"><map:value/></map:entry></map:map>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}, local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="content-type"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">mu...</map:map>)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $endpoint-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="upload"><map:value/></map:entry></map:map>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $input = document{binary{""}}
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy, at 65:8 [1.0-ml]
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="upload"><map:value/></map:entry></map:map>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="content-type"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">mu...</map:map>)
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $method = "POST"
2016-02-15 17:29:32.085 Notice: content-repo:   $body = document{binary{""}}
2016-02-15 17:29:32.216 Info: content-repo: Status 500: XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoLoad","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/repoLoad/assets/resource.xqy")($context, $service-params, $input) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MarkLogic REST extensions run in particular update modes by default, depending on request method and single/multi statement. Since MarkLogic 8 the default update mode for POST method single statement was changed to `query`. Add an annotation to your `repoLoad:post` method like follows:

```
declare %rapi:transaction-mode("update") function repoLoad:post(...)
```

See also the [REST Application Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_17130).

HTH!

Comment: Yup that did the trick..  I was looking at rewrite.xml ,

`<match-path matches="^/(v1|LATEST)/resources/([^/]+)/?$">
            <match-method any-of="GET HEAD POST">
                <match-query-param name="txid">
                    <set-transaction>$0</set-transaction>
                    <set-transaction-mode>query</set-transaction-mode>
                </match-query-param>
                <dispatch>/MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy</dispatch>
            </match-method>`

adding this how will the execution logic changes :) ? so I can stop asking stupid questions

Comment: MarkLogic has built-in defaults, and the rewrite.xml provides REST api specific defaults on top of that. But you can override the defaults. With regular code with a declare option on top of your code, but these REST extensions require this little annotation to toggle the update mode.